# Get range count between low and high with step

Tags: python

This might be a stupid question, but I'm drawing a blank. I'm looking to get the max possible numbers/instances between a low and high number with step.

For example, given this dictionary:

```
dictionary_one = {"low": -2.0, "high": 2.0, "step": 0.1}
```

... I want this output

```
41
```

... as that is the total of all possible combinations between that range (i.e. -2.0, -1.9, -1.8, ..., 1.8, 1.9, 2.0). The low and high should be inclusive.

Preferably without using a for loop for the count, but whatever works. Thanks!

Comment: Well, what is the mathematical formula that tells you how many steps there are? How would you solve the problem with pencil and paper? When you wrote in your post that the answer is `41`, did you figure this out by writing all of them out? Or did you do some kind of math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total = ((abs(dictionary_one["low"]) + abs(dictionary_one["high"]))/dictionary_one["step"]) + 1
```